# How to replace word in notepad++ that begins with certain word plus number of bytes

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I want to replace that number with format of `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` with "".

For example: `20130618100147    SOME TEXT HERE`

I tried the to find the `2013(.*)$` in notepad++ (Regular Exp, Wraparound) but every word that next to 2013 deleted in the same line. How can I able to replace only the word starting with `2013` plus the 10 bytes?

Comment: what if I want to replace so many words and approximately all starts with
a particular alphabet or no. so how we can do that . ? 
For Example, `M28BB139 / M28CT132`(it's more than k in no.) need to replace with `CCRT23`

Answer (score 2):

`2013\d{10}` will match 2013 and 10 digits after it.

UPD:

Here's a slightly improved version of the regex:

```
2013[0,1][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]
```

that will still match, for example, `20130601000000` because it's a valid timestamp.

Comment: But for example: 20130601000000201306041023332013060300000020130611000000 I want to disregard 2013****000000 that ends with 6 zeros, How I will do that?

Comment: @PeterS hm, so any other timestamp except `2013****000000` should be counted, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
(2013\d{10})
```

This will match and capture the entire string. then you will just need a `regex.replace` to get rid of it.

---

Capture anything up until the first occurrence of a space???

```
(2013\d*\s)
```